# Remove unicode characters from set elements?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy, python-unicode

new to python. I am writing a scraper and it yields a set of values which all have unicode characters.

I'm wondering how to remove the unicode characters from it. I was under the impression I'm using python3 but I can't tell because the command is scrapy, and I always use python2. Never used a tool which doesn't use the python command to run.

```
import scrapy


class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "quotes"

    def start_requests(self):
        urls = [
            'http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/1/',
            'http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/2/',
        ]
        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)



    def parse(self, response):
        for quote in response.css('div.quote'):
            yield {
                'text': quote.css('span.text::text').extract_first(),
                'author': quote.css('small.author::text').extract_first(),
                'tags': quote.css('div.tags a.tag::text').extract(),
                }
```

The command to run is

```
scrapy crawl quotes -o output.json
```

How do I remove the unicode characters from the response or the items in the yielded set?

Comment: All characters in a utf8-coded page are Unicode characters (even _these_). What exactly do you want to remove?

Comment: @DYZ In the 'text' attributes contents for every record there's a '\u201c' at the beginning. I could parse it out obviously but that will only get me so far.

Comment: Why don't you replace with a`''`?

Comment: @DYZ yeah that's what I did(replace '\u201c' with ' '), but is there a way to automatically remove unicode chars without hardcoding that?

Comment: These `“` ([U+201c](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/201c/index.htm) and [U+201d](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/201c/index.htm)) characters are part of the data in those pages. _"I could parse it out obviously_" and this is what one usually does: if you want to strip some characters from a Python string, you can use `.strip()`, e.g. in this case `quote.css('span.text::text').extract_first().strip(u'\u201c\u201d')`

Comment: @paultrmbrth cool got it thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

Try it this way:

```
...
'text': quote.css('span.text::text').extract_first().decode('unicode_escape').encode('ascii', 'ignore')
...
```

Answer (score 0):

This code should be worked

```
yield {
  'text': quote.css('span.text::text').extract_first().encode("utf-8").decode('unicode_escape').encode('ascii', 'ignore'),
  'author': quote.css('small.author::text').extract_first().encode("utf-8").decode('unicode_escape').encode('ascii', 'ignore'),
  'tags': quote.css('div.tags a.tag::text').extract().encode("utf-8").decode('unicode_escape').encode('ascii', 'ignore'),
}
```

Or you can create a function to convert unicode to string,

```
def convertToString(encodedString):
     return encodedString.encode("utf-8").decode('unicode_escape').encode('ascii', 'ignore')
```

Answer (score 0):

I implemeted the same using **Items** to give appropriate structure to the data as descibed here : [Scrapy documentation](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/items.html)

*items.py*

```py
class QuotesItem(scrapy.Item):
    title = scrapy.Field()
    author = scrapy.Field()
    tag = scrapy.Field()
```

*Spider*

```py
import scrapy
from ..items import QuotesItem

class QuotesSpiderSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'quotes_spider'
    # allowed_domains = ['http://quotes.toscrape.com/']
    start_urls = ['http://quotes.toscrape.com/']

    def parse(self, response):
        items = QuotesItem()
        all_div_quotes = response.css("div.quote")

        for quote in all_div_quotes:
            title = quote.css('span.text::text').extract_first()
            author = quote.css('.author::text').extract_first()
            tags = quote.css("a.tag::text").extract()
             
            items['title'] = title.strip(u'\u201c\u201d')       #strip unicode chars u'\u201c\u201d 
            items['author'] = author
            items['tag'] = ", ".join(str(x) for x in tags)      #convert list to string separated by commas

            yield items
```

To run

```py
scrapy crawl quotes_spider -o output.json
```